# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!\left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm currently studying for my exam next month and I'm struggling to calculate the radius of convergence of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n!\left ( \frac{z^n}{n} \right )^n$$
In class we always had easier ones like
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!z^n$$ where we could simply use the following formula: 
$R=\frac{1}{\varlimsup |a_n|^{(1/n)}}$

So how could I caluclate the radius of convergence of my original series?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use Stirling's formula $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (\tfrac ne)^n$

Comment: By [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n = 1$$

Hence $$\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$

Answer (score 4):

If you rewrite it as:

$$\sum a_kz^k$$

with $$a_k=\begin{cases}\frac{n!}{n^n}&k=n^2\\0&k\text{ is not a perfect square}\end{cases}$$

Then:
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty} |a_k|^{1/k}=\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_{n^2}|^{1/n^2}$$

And we have:

$$\frac{1}{n^n}\leq a_{n^2}\leq 1$$

So:

$$\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}\leq |a_{n^2}|^{1/n^2}\leq 1$$

By the squeeze theorem, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1/n}}=1$, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}  |a_{n^2}|^{1/n^2}=1$.

So we get a radius of convergence of $1$.

Comment: Great! Can you please elaborate on the value of $a_k$ (especially) when $k$ is not a perfect square. I don't fully understand that yet. Thank you.

Comment: What is the coefficient of $z^3$ in the original formula? What is the coefficient of $z^5$?

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\frac{(n+1)!\left(\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{n!\left(\frac{z^n}n\right)^n}=n\frac{\frac{z^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}{\frac{z^{n^2}}{n^n}}=\frac n{n+1}z^{2n+1}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n$$and since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n=\frac1e,$$the series converges absolutely if $|z|<1$ and diverges if $|z|>1$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Is $|z|<\dfrac{1}{e}$ or |z|<1?

Comment: @scarface It's $|z|<1$. Why do you ask?

Comment: There is problem. I made a mistake. Now, I see that the question has $z^{n^2}$ terms. So the series is diverges for $|z|>1$. Your solution is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The radius of convergence $\rho$ of a power series of the form $\sum a_n z^{n^2}$ can be evaluated by

$$\rho=\frac1{\limsup|a_n|^{1/n^2}}$$

because the other coefficients are zero, so they doesnt add anything to the limit superior. In this case we have

$$\rho=\frac1{\limsup|a_n|^{1/n^2}}=\frac1{\lim (n!/n^n)^{1/n^2}}=\frac1{\lim( \sqrt{2\pi n}e^{-n})^{1/n^2}}=1$$

were we used the Stirling asymptotic $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (\tfrac ne)^n$ when $n$ goes to infinity and the known fact that $\lim C^{1/n}=\lim n^{1/n}=1$ for any $C>0$.

Comment: I almost went with Stirling, but you really only nead $\frac{1}{n^n}\leq a_n\leq 1$ to get the result.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, you are totally right